# Remove item from list if a string from another object contains substring

Tags: python

I am trying to remove items from **slices(list)** whose substring is a part of **pic(string)** value from **status2**. I have tried various ways but there is always some issue such as sometimes it doesn't iterate over every item, sometimes it returns the exact same list.

```
slices = ['face_06_01.png', 'face_B45_06_01.png', 'face_gh_06_01.png', 'face_HJ_06_01.png']
status2 = [{'key': 1, 'pic': 'face_01_01.png', 'status': 2}, {'key': 2, 'pic': 'face__B45_02_01.png', 'status': 2}, {'key': 4, 'pic': 'face_gh_04_01.png', 'status': 2}]

for part in slices:
    pic_name = part[:-10]
    for status2_pic in status2:
        if pic_name in status2_pic['pic']:
            slices.remove(part)
            break
```

Output I get:

```
slices = ['face_B45_06_01.png', 'face_HJ_06_01.png']
```

Output I want according to the sample data:

```
slices = ['face_HJ_06_01.png']
```

This is where I am testing the code for now:
[image]

Comment: CAn you provide an example where this does *not* work?

Comment: Your code gives the output you need. What is the issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate, because from looking at your code I believe you're running into the common problem in Python of removing items from a list while iterating over it, which can cause exactly the kinds of problems you're describing.  One quick workaround is to duplicate the list when iterating over it like `for part in slices[:]:`

Comment: I have updated the code @Ram

Comment: Please see the example in the code. I have updated it. @CutePoison

Comment: Tried it but not getting the right output. @Iguananaut

Comment: Note that you have a double under-score in `key:2` `face__B45`

Comment: Could you explain the output you want. How are you getting that ? @alibaig

Comment: Fixed the type but still the same result @CutePoison

Comment: I am trying to remove items from slices(list) whose substring is a part of pic(string) value from status2. I have mentioned the output I want in the question. @Ram

Comment: I mean add an example in your question and explain us how you are getting that output you wanted. So ```f``` is a substring in all the items of ```slices``` and all values of ```pic```. Does that mean you have to remove everything from ```slices``` ?

Comment: The list of Slices contains file names as I have provided the sample list in the question.  The other variable is status2 which has a pic(string) in it. I want to match the start of pic(String) such as in the case of face_BHd_01_01.png; it would be face_BHD, in case of face_01_01.png; it would be face. Now I want to match face_BHD and face with each value of slices if this substring is a part of slices item values, then that item should be removed from the slices.

Comment: Ok. So for ```face_gh_06_01.png``` the slice is ```face_gh```; ```face_HJ_06_01.png``` the slice is ```face_HJ```. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. You don't have to remove the items one by one. List comprehensions are your friend :)

```
slices = [slice for slice in slices if slice[:-10] not in str(list(map(lambda x: x['pic'], status2)))]
```

Comment: Did you run this ? What output did you get ?

Comment: No, but I am fairly confident it will run. Did it cause a problem in your end?

Comment: No. It wont't. Try running it and see for yourself. You will understand the problem.

Comment: status2 is not a list so it will cause an error.

Comment: changed the comment to work with a list of dictionaries

Comment: It doesn't remove anything @alparslanmimaroğlu

Comment: Yes it did not check for substrings. I edited the code again. Now it also checks for substrings

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this using **List Comprehension**.

- I am using `.startswith()` to specifically filter out results that start with the substring.
- If you just want that substring to exists irrespective of position. **Use `in`**.

  > `if s in i['pic']:`

```
slices = ['face_06_01.png', 'face_B45_06_01.png', 'face_gh_06_01.png', 'face_HJ_06_01.png']
status2 = [{'key': 1, 'pic': 'face_01_01.png', 'status': 2}, {'key': 2, 'pic': 'face__B45_02_01.png', 'status': 2}, {'key': 4, 'pic': 'face_gh_04_01.png', 'status': 2}]

def check(s):
    for i in status2:
        if i['pic'].startswith(s):
            return True
    return False

slices = [x for x in slices if not check(x[:-9])]

print(slices)
```

```
['face_B45_06_01.png', 'face_HJ_06_01.png']
```

Comment: `slices = ['face_HJ_06_01.png']` It should return this but thank you for the help.

Comment: It's working fine. there's was a typo in face__B45  which should be face_B45 and then it would display the correct result